# error while loading shared libraries: libiomp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, openmp, icc, intel-parallel-studio

I installed Intel® Parallel Studio XE Composer Edition for C++ Linux to use OpenMP 4.0. I compile example code with

> icc example.c -openmp -o example

When I run ./example I have an error:

> ./example: error while loading shared libraries: libiomp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 6):

In a HPC, I got the same message if I do not run `module load intel` firstly.

Another ref:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/271099

Comment: This worked for me. Despite having module load intel in bashrc.local.blah, submitting a job still gave the libiomp5.so error. Had to put module load intel in the job script.

Comment: From the link supplied, `source /opt/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64` worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dependency on the libiomp5.so module. Check to see if your machine already has this module installed by running $find / -name libiomp5.so and if the module is not found, then install it and put it in the modules folder that your program is looking in.

Answer (score -1):

With Intel compiler you should use `-qopenmp`.

Comment: This doesn't work at all for me. I get ``icc: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '-qopenmp'``

Comment: That's strange. Which version of `ICC`?